# How could we cut out a map object in a layout?

Tags: android, maps

I have a problem with the integration of a map and an app, I want to do a wrapping a map in a part of the main frame (as the attached image).
The problem is that when I call it, it fill it the whole screen
[image: oid a]

//java class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    Button firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
     "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:51.5, 0.125"));


    firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Map.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

//xml

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/MapView"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="322dp"
  />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/left" 
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? Can't determine the problem if we can't see the problem to begin with.

Comment: Nero there are the full code , thanks